# Adding butterknife to android library project gives compile time error "package does not exists" for library classes

Tags: android, compiler-errors, build.gradle, android-library, butterknife

I was trying to add butterknife library to my library project and followed the steps.

```
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife.
```

The project does not show any error while gradle sync, but when I am trying to run the application it returns compile error package does not exits for my library classes which I have used in the application.

```
error

error:package com.sample.library.BaseMainActivity does not exist
error:cannot find symbol class BaseMainActivity
error:cannot find symbol variable super

project/build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.test"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "v3.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ButterKnife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

library/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'

    //Dagger
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    // ButterKnife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

The application runs error free if I remove the ButterKnife dependencies. Somehow the library project is conflicting with butterknife library but not able find out why and how. Please help what am I doing wrong in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything compiles without a problem if `Dagger` version inside the `library` is upgraded.

Use:

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your libraries in my app and it builds ok

here is the gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()


dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
}
}
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
compile 'net.grandcentrix.tray:tray:0.9.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'

//Dagger
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```